# Show total progress of all uploading files using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, progress-bar

I've written a script with jQuery and PHP, which allows to upload multiple files. I've done it so far, that i can see the progress of each file uploading. I'm using the object XMLHttpRequest for this issue. Now I want to show on the top of alle uploading progress file bars, the current status of all uploading files.

Any how to do that?

**Note**: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) is what I'm using for each file upload ajax call.

Comment: That's mathematically the sum of all `loaded` divided by the sum of all `total`. Maybe you can store them in an Array and update that array upon every progress. But then, for a more detailed answer, ou should post some code.

Comment: @AugustoMen Thanks! I'm saving the loaded size of each file in an array and print as you said the sum of all loaded divided by the sum of all total.